# Why does a nested python dictionary not work if it is created with a for-loop when you want to change a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, python-3.7

If I have a nested Python dictionary created by writing all keys and values I can then change a value in an inner dictionary by the following: `mainDict[outerKey][innerKey] = NewValue`. But if I create the exact same dictionary with for-loops, when I try to change an inner value it gets changed for all inner dictionaries. Why is that?

I have tested to get the values and type of values for every part of this and all seem to be exactly the same for both an explicitly written nested dictionary and for a nested dictionary written with the for-loops.

## Example1 with nested dictionary written explicitly:

```py
outerDict = {'outerA': {'innerA': 0, 'innerB': 0}, 'outerB': {'innerA': 0, 'innerB': 0}}

outer = 'outerB'
inner = 'innerB'
outerDict['outerB']['innerB'] = 'New Value'

print(outerDict)
```

> result: {'outerA': {'innerA': 0, 'innerB': 0}, 'outerB': {'innerA': 0, 'innerB': 'New Value'}}

## Example2 with nested dictionary written using for-loops:

```py
def dictCreate(outerKeys, innerKeys):
    innerDict = dict()
    for innerKey in innerKeys:
        innerDict[innerKey] = 0

    outerDict = dict()
    for outerKey in outerKeys:
        outerDict[outerKey] = innerDict
    return outerDict

outerKeys = ['outerA', 'outerB']
innerKeys = ['innerA', 'innerB']
outerDict = dictCreate(outerKeys, innerKeys)
outer = 'outerB'
inner = 'innerB'
outerDict['outerB']['innerB'] = 'New Value'

print(outerDict)
```

> result: {'outerA': {'innerA': 0, 'innerB': 'New Value'}, 'outerB': {'innerA': 0, 'innerB': 'New Value'}}

Note that in the example of the explicitly written nested dictionary the only value that is changed is the value in the outer dictionary "outerB" / inner dictionary "innerB".

But in the example created with for-loops the value for the inner dictionary, "innerB" is changed in both outer dictionaries. How can this be? Or am I the only one getting these results?

Comment: because you're using the same `innerDict` object, so changing one changes all

Comment: As an aside, if you're initializing all the keys to the same value, you don't need an explicit loop at all; You can use `innerDict = dict.fromkeys(innerKeys, 0)`.

Comment: OK, thanks! I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same object, i.e. the same reference every loop of the outer. So when you change one, you change them all.

```
def dictCreate(outerKeys, innerKeys):
    innerDict = dict()
    for innerKey in innerKeys:
        innerDict[innerKey] = 0

    outerDict = dict()
    for outerKey in outerKeys:
        outerDict[outerKey] = innerDict # Here you are using the same list every iteration
    return outerDict
```

to fix this you must construct a new list every loop:

```
def dictCreate(outerKeys, innerKeys):
    outerDict = dict()
    for outerKey in outerKeys:
        innerDict = dict()
        for innerKey in innerKeys:
            innerDict[innerKey] = 0
        outerDict[outerKey] = innerDict # Here you are now using a new list every iteration
    return outerDict
```

you can make this nicer by using dict comprehensions

```
outerDict =  { outerKey : {innerKey : 0 for innerKey in innerKeys} for outerKey in outerKeys}
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Because they are the same dictionary, referenced from 2 different places.

Comment: Thanks! Seems obvious to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop:

```
 for outerKey in outerKeys:
     outerDict[outerKey] = innerDict
```

gives each of the outer dictionaries a reference to *the same* `innerDict` - which is why any change to `innderDict` is seen in all the `outerDict` values

This is completely expected (in the 'Python working as designed' sense) behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! I get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @Scott Hunter says you use 2 you *referenced from 2 different places.*

You should know how python handles [mutable vs immutable objects](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutable-vs-immutable-objects-in-python/).

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.